# Where can I find publicly available anonymized employee data from companies?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for some data about employees of some (any) company, such as surveys, exit interviews etc. If there are no such datasets available, then suggestions on how to gather such data would also work.

Comment: This seems like a very broad request. Can you be more specific? Are you looking for quantified data or text? In general, this seems like the kind of thing which might be more effectively found by reviewing business literature (case studies, etc) looking for either provided data or contacts who might share it.

Comment: Thanks Joe Germuska for your reply. I am modeling employee attrition. So I am in need of data to train and validate such model. I assume most of these type of data is textual.

Comment: you are probably looking for the national compensation survey, a survey run by the bureau of labor statistics. it is public but requires you to be on-site.

Comment: @user5567 it may help if you edit your original question to elaborate so that anyone who might answer can readily see what you need.

Comment: I doubt anyone would make that available freely ... too much opportunity for privacy violations.  You might be able to get really high level data like attrition rates from payroll companies like ADP, but I have a feeling they'd charge for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Employee Churn dataset?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/employee-churn-dataset)