# Employee Churn dataset?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a `dataset` for `Employee churn/Labor Turnover` prediction. I looked around but couldn't find any relevant `dataset` to download. Following are some of the features I am looking in the `dataset` (Its not mandatory feature set but anything on this line will be good):

```
Age
Degree
Salary
Promotion in last year?
score of employee
Tenure
Performance rating
```

Can anyone provide me link where I can download such `dataset`?

Comment: A nice churn one is from telecom and related to calling records - see the [churn.names](https://www.sgi.com/tech/mlc/db/churn.names) file and then churn.* https://www.sgi.com/tech/mlc/db/ for the data

Comment: BLS (Bureau of Labor Statistics) offers 'Turnover Rate' date, but that's not at the level of specificity that you're looking for : http://www.bls.gov/jlt/

Answer (score 2):

difficult to provide because confidentiality is much harder for firms than it is for individuals and households.  to access real data, you would need to apply for access to something like the `national compensation survey` and access the data on-site at the bureau of labor statistics.  census and bls have a few different firm (or establishment)-level surveys -- all of them restricted-use.

you can experiment with synthetic open data, however: http://lehd.ces.census.gov/

Comment: A synthetic data will also suffice as my need is for just for a proof.

Answer (score 1):

How about the **[Employee Turnover dataset](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~pspector/sasdir/datasets.html)** from the book "[SAS Programming For Researchers and Social Scientists](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~pspector/sasdir/sasprogramming.html)"

The data is column based, and contains:

- work frustration scale
- job satisfaction scale
- Intent to quit
- Quit?
- Age
- Tenure on the job

**[Raw Data](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~pspector/sasdir/turnover.dat)** - *reference:* Spector, P. E., Dwyer, D. J., & Jex, S. M. (1988). Relation of job stressors to affective, health, and performance outcomes: A comparison of multiple data sources. Journal of Applied Psychology, 73, 11-19.

[image]

---

Another idea: not based on individual turnover, but there is turnover data from the State of Oklahoma employees that is broken down by job sector - [LINK](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/fiscal-year-2012-turnover-rate-by-job-family-level-07e61/resource/d08b65c5-3a9b-4865-b88e-9a2b6b5d65a1)

There is something similar for GLA (Greater London Area) - [LINK](http://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/gla-staff-turnover-2009)

Answer (score 0):

A popular dataset for this purpose is provided by IBM, and can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/communities/analytics/watson-analytics-blog/hr-employee-attrition/).

Columns include:

- Age
- Attrition
- BusinessTravel
- Department
- Education
- Gender
- JobLevel
- OverTime
- TotalWorkingYears

Another dataset is found at this [Kaggle page](https://www.kaggle.com/HRAnalyticRepository/employee-attrition-data/data). Both of these datasets are synthetic, i.e. not real company data.